# Chrome policies not being applied?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to apply Chrome policies to every user, but when I follow [these instructions](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start), it doesn't work.

Has anyone successfully applied Chrome policies using this method?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own issue - When Chrome installs, it creates a directory `/etc/opt/google/chrome`.

The instructions clearly state to create the policy directories in `/etc/opt/chrome`, but I overthought it and placed them in `/etc/opt/google/chrome`.

Once I moved them to `/etc/opt/chrome/` it worked!